# Ошибка "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой "cannot find symbol":

```
class Quadrate {
double a; 

Quadrate (double a){
    this.a = a;
}

double perimeter() {
    double value = 4 * a;
    return value;
}

double square() {
    double value = a * a;
    return value;
}

double diagonal() {
    double value = Math.sqrt(a * a + a * a);
    return value;
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.print("Введите кол-во квадратов: ");
    while (true) {
        if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Некорректний тип введеного числа! Повторите попитку: ");
            sc.next();
        } else {
            n = sc.nextInt();
            break;
        }
    }
    Quadrate[] quadrates = new Quadrate[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < quadrates.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Введите сторону %d - го: ", i + 1);
        double v = sc.nextDouble();
        quadrates[i] = new Quadrate(v);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < quadrates.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Периметр %d - го: %f", i + 1, qudrates[i].perimeter()); // ошибка
        System.out.printf("Площадь %d - го: %f", i + 1, qudrates[i].square()); // ошибка
        System.out.printf("Диагональ %d - го: %f", i + 1, qudrates[i].diagonal()); // ошибка
    }
}
}
```

Также  можно вводить только челочисельные значения стороны, а при double - ошибка, если не затруднит, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ниже "cannot find symbol" компилятор показывает какой "символ" не находится. Описание ошибки должно быть чуть более полным чем "не смогла". По приведенному коду возникает вопрос - а кто такой Scanner? `import java.util.Scanner;` - есть? Или указываете полностью.

Comment: есть просто не писал

Comment: сканнер импортировал сразу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В самой ошибке `cannot find symbol` указано, что `symbol:   variable qudrates`

У вас опечатка. Ваш массив называется `quadrates`, но в некоторых строках вы используете `qudrates`

Comment: Точно. Спасибо. Просто немного устал уже, вот и не заметил бред. Но есть еще проблема                                                                              Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
 at quadrate.Main.main(Main.java:46)

Comment: @MuscledBoy Попытайтесь найти ответ на вопрос самостоятельно. Если не получится — создайте ещё один вопрос.

Comment: ок, спасибо и на этом

Comment: ошибка была в вводе числа. 1.2, например, будет 1,2 - правильно